# parsing json with high level "unknown" names

Tags: json, jackson

How do you parse a JSON structure such as this

```
  "properties": {
    "/base/pinball/pinball_machine_basis/pinball_machines": {
      "expected_type": {
        "id": "/base/pinball/pinball_machine",
        "text": "Pinball Machine"
      },
      "text": "Pinball Machines",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": "/m/026z8cp",
          "text": "The Lord of the Rings",
          "url": "http://www.freebase.com/view/m/026z8cp"
        }
      ]
    },
    "/common/topic/article": {
      "expected_type": {
        "id": "/common/document",
        "text": "Document"
      },
      "text": "article",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": "/m/025h5z",
          "text": "",
          "url": "http://www.freebase.com/view/m/025h5z"
        }
      ]
    },
    "/common/topic/image": {
      "expected_type": {
        "id": "/common/image",
        "text": "Image"
      },
      "text": "image",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": "/m/029wvk4",
          "text": "The Lord of the Rings: The Motion Picture Trilogy poster (2003)",
          "url": "http://www.freebase.com/view/m/029wvk4"
        },
        {
          "id": "/m/0bdyf3j",
          "text": "",
          "url": "http://www.freebase.com/view/m/0bdyf3j"
        },
        {
          "id": "/m/0glyg_4",
          "text": "lotr-extended-blu-ray.jpg",
          "url": "http://www.freebase.com/view/m/0glyg_4"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I will not know in advance the high level names such as "/base/pinball/pinball_machine_basis/pinball_machines", "/common/topic/article", or "/exhibitions/exhibition_subject/exhibitions_created_about_this_subject"

i have tried Jackson but cannot see how to generate a java class that matches this structure. it apears to be an array but isnt surrounded with "[" or "]".

the structure repeats "expected_type", "text", "values" etc. what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having hit a brick wall with this problem i contacted Tatu Saloranta
who was extremely helpful. with his help i managed to complete my Freebase Explorer Android Application. I have made my android application source code available in GITHUB if anyone is interested.

[GITHUB source Code](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Api_Examples)

The android application is also available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.free.base.surfer&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmZyZWUuYmFzZS5zdXJmZXIiXQ..)

Answer (score 1):

Well. I have the same problem. But your answer is not very helpful for me. I am sure you created a great app and I am happy for you that you could solve the problem. But I have no time to dig through your source code on GitHub. I would really appreciate if you could just post the code snippet which solves the problem. Many Thanks.

After some research I found this solution here with @JsonAnySetter:

```
private Map<String, Object> all = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, Object value) {
    all.put(name, value);
}

public Map<String, Object> getAll() {
    return all;
}

public void setAll(Map<String, Object> all) {
    this.all = all;
}
```

With this Annotation you can handle any kind of unknown properties in a JSON stream. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this code/hint. I somehow missed the annotation you mentioned. Anyway I have to parse json that has the language code as attribute names so I would have to check for 200+ languages. The code made it way easier!